# KineticJS Container.getIntersections very slow

Tags: canvas, collision-detection, kineticjs, intersection

I need to detect collisions in my HTML5 canvas (I'm using the KineticJS library), and thus far have used my own methods to detect if a certain point is within a certain shape.

I recently noticed that there's a method from the Container class, getIntersections(point) which should do exactly what I want. However it seems to be EXTREMELY slow, so when moving an object on the canvas and using the method for every new position, it becomes unusable.

Has anyone used this method for collision detection? If not, are there any tips on collision detection in a HTML5 canvas? I'm having trouble detecting if a point is inside a rectangle that is rotated by a certain amount of degrees.

Comment: can you make an example code? I have some usage of more than 10000 shapes with animation and its not slow using mouseover. I do hovever use many different layers and place the mouse events on the layer and put different shapes into different layers. (kineticjs 4.1.2 version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/issues/150

This is exactly what you need.

> okay, to be clear, there are two ways to get an intersected shape
>   based on mouse position:
>
> 1) getIntersection() - preferred 2) getIntersections() - very slow,
>   and should be used for special situations
>
> the getIntersection() method is blazingly fast, and returns an object
>   containing information about the intersection point, such as a
>   reference to a KineticJS shape if one is there, or pixel color
>   information.
>
> the getIntersections() method does the same thing, except that it
>   iterates through and redraws every single node in the stage in order
>   to return a collection of intersections that may have been layered on
>   top of eachother.
>
> 99 times out of a 100, you're probably just interested in the visible
>   intersected node which is at the top of nodes beneath it.
>
> I've actually considered removing the getIntersections() method
>   entirely, but haven't because there are some special situations when
>   you actually do need a collection of intersections. At this time, I
>   haven't been able to find a way to speed up getIntersections, although
>   I'll keep looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed the same thing, getIntersections takes a long time. It is also called for mouse events etc. which makes it even worse.

I don't know how to make it faster, but one thing that affects the speed considerably is the number of Shapes you have on your stage. So one way to speed things up would be to remove unnecessary Shapes when they are not needed and bring them back dynamically when needed.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've actually tried it with just 1 other shape in the layer, but it still slows the application down to the unusable.

Comment: Is this correct? I was under the assumption that on mouseover used the getIntersections and that is fast for that (see http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-interactive-scatter-plot-with-20000-nodes-using-kineticjs/)

Comment: @Jonke I based my comment to the fact that when I run Chrome profiler against my kineticjs project to see where it uses CPU time, it says Kinetic.Stage.getIntersection takes over 46%! When I click to open it to see where it is used, it displays three places: Kinetic.Stage._mousemove, _mousedown and _mouseup. Mousemove takes 45% so basically all of the getIntersection cpu time.

Comment: @pillar yes getIntersection does take CPU time but does it takes cpu time more than it should? (aka slow code)? I think that the OP uses getIntersection for a home brew collision detection and maybe he should override the current behavior when on mouse[move] so he don't fire getIntersection multiple times.

Comment: @Jonke According to this, yes it does: [link](https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/issues/150).

Answer (score 1):

I have used getIntersection() in a mobile game (a simulation for air traffic control) and it worked quite well given that it was called multiple number of times to detect a collision among all the existing planes in the game frame. In case you have to detect just one specific point, a possible solution could be to add a very small dummy rectangle for that place and get list of all objects intersecting with it and iterate over this list. Naming the objects of interest can speed up your condition verification.